# percona-server-server-5.7 not available anymore?

Tags: apt, database

I followed the APT installation instruction here https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/installation/apt_repo.html

but it seems not working anymore with this error message

```
root@server# apt-get install percona-server-server-5.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package percona-server-server-5.7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7:i386 percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
```

Anyone facing the same issue? is percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7 the same with percona-server-server-5.7

UPDATE: Issue has been fixed now

Comment: "root@server# " bad behaviour. Use sudo for this as this will use your admin for it. or are you perhaps not using Ubuntu. "is percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7 the same with percona-server-server-5.7 "..."However the following packages replace it:" seems to indicate it. What happend whten you installed `percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7`?  This is something you would need to as the people from persona. Maybe they forgot to update the package list.

Comment: @Rinzwind I just replaced the original hostname with root@server to remove private information. I am using Ubuntu btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been raised as an issue in their Jira see here https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-5615

Apparently someone is looking into it.

I guess you just need a bit of patience now.

Comment: update the issue has been fixed now https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-5615?focusedCommentId=238465&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-238465